# Posting code and formatting

Tags: support, code-formatting

Every time I use `pre code` formatting I get two awkward (somehow nested) scroll bars on the side. What am I doing wrong, formatting, copying?

[image]

[Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144172/subset-sum-problem-implementation)

---

<sup>Beyond the trivial reasons.</sup>

Comment: You're posting so much code that a scrollbar is needed.  Be more concise.

Comment: do you have an example question/answer where this is happening?

Comment: You've posted plenty of questions on SO that format their code properly.  Do what you did there, rather than applying two separate formatting mechanisms when you don't want both formatting mechanisms to be applied.

Comment: You basically got a code block within a code block. Looks like a bug. I would avoid any `<pre>` or `<code>` and always format the code block with four spaces.

Comment: @Floern This is what I usually do, but in Code Review I post more code and it's getting tedious to format _"by hand"_, i.e. using 4 spaces.

Comment: You don't have to format by hand, you can format with your favourite editor, copy-paste, select the code and then indent it all at once with Ctrl-K or the `{}` button.

Comment: Generally, if you see a scrollbar in your code, you're already doing something wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem was the `<pre><code>` tags; you don't need them. Just highlight the code and use the code sample button in the toolbar above the textbox.

[image: Code sample]

This will add four spaces at the start of every line you highlighted. [Here is the edit history showing they were in there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/144172/revisions).

I suspect the problem was that it was trying to do a code sample inside a code sample, because after the first few lines you then had four spaces at the start of lines, and the code sample puts scrollbars in automatically when there is a lot of code.